# How can Proxy and Facade design patterns be combined?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, facade, proxy-pattern

I have a third party library class `Lib` and an own `LibProxy` where `LibProxy` adds some caching before passign the control to `Lib`. This would have been textbook Proxy, but `LibProxy` also simplifies the interface to `Lib`. Which also makes it a Facade.

What is the course of action here? Making `LibProxy` comply to the interface of `Lib` and adding a separate `LibFacade` feels like overkill. This is what it would look like: `Client`->`LibFacade`->`LibProxy`->`Lib`.

Can I call it `LibProxyFacade` instead? Or is there some other pattern that is equivalent to the Proxy/Facade combination?

Answer (score 1):

I would say don't overthink it: the patterns are there to show us a way of solving some of the common problems, but it doesn't mean they are always the right/only way. I like this talk by Venkat where he is presenting some patterns, but he starts the presentation with the cons of overengineering: https://youtu.be/yTuwi--LFsM?t=238

Back to your question: does `ProxyLib` really need to implement the same interface as `Lib` for any reason (other than following the Proxy pattern)? Why not change the interface (and maybe rename the class to something else like `LibFacade` or `LibAdapter`?

If you want to implement an interface, I would place it in inside your domain, and have this facade/adapter implement it by mapping, adding some caching, and delegating to `Lib`. This is called *dependency inversion* and helps you protect your logic against the changes in the public API of the lib. If this is interesting to you, here is a blog post from Uncle Bob:
https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. LibFacade may be a good option, but then it doesn't convey the intent about caching that LibProxy had. I am still wondering which of the two is more important. :) BTW in my language, DI is kinda built in - a class is also an interface, no need to create an explicit interface.

Comment: I see, but still: if you use the raw types/objects specified y the lib, your logic will still depend on it, even if it is your interface, it's not a true DI - if you know what I mean. In other words, you won't easily switch to a different lib if needed. On the other hand, if you create your own abstraction (by making the API more friendly/simplifying it, as you already said) you will have more flexibility.

Comment: I depend on the interface of `LibProxy` (the simplified one), not on `Lib`'s.

Comment: is it ok then :)